# How do I create an external site iframe that uses php as proxy through my webserver? (avoiding CORS)

Tags: javascript, php, html, curl, cross-domain

I found an example to use curl in php, this is what I've done so far:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="fetch.php" width="800" height="500"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

fetch.php:

```
    ini_set ( "allow_url_fopen", "On" );

    $url = "http://www.google.com/";
    $ch = curl_init ();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    $data = curl_exec ( $ch );
    curl_close ( $ch );
    echo $data;
```

This will show: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7l4b1.jpg

Questions:

1. How do I get it to show the images and data in my iframe? (currently 404 error as it tries to find the images on my webserver)
2. How am I able to navigate inside this iframe? For example if I search on google in that iframe I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjWm8.jpg

Comment: I have a question. Why are you using an iframe? What is the point in this case? You're taking advantage of CUrl and therefore the iFrame is really just the same as `<div><?php require_once('fetch.php'); ?> </div>`.

Comment: iframe seemed convenient, I'm not experienced enough to know the code line you gave me, but it just gave me a blank page.

Comment: try str_replacing the data before echoing it. `str_replace('href="/', 'href="http://www.example.com/')` for example.

Answer (score 0):

What your code does is download the page source at the given url (in this case '`http://www.google.com/`'). It's effectively the same as going to a webpage, clicking on "view source" and copy/paste the source code.

If you wish to retain the original looks of the page coupled with ability to navigate in the iframe, then you don't need cURL, you just need to change point your iframe to that page.

Please note that it won't work with www.google.com, since it sends the "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" header in the response, preventing iframe inclusion, at least in compliant browsers.

Comment: How do proxies do it? For example if I use hidemyass public proxy on google inside my iframe, it works perfectly with images and searching. Is there a way to make your webserver proxying in that fashion?